# How is the TSM ADRs USD value calculated?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-valuation, adr

1 share of TSM is supposed to be backed by 5 shares of 2330.TWSE, that is the TSMCs stocks trading in the Taiwan Stock Exchange.

I just can't figure out the USD valuation: As an example, as of Oct 18, 2023 close, 1 share of 2330.TWSE was 540TWD. When we do the math, 5 * 540 = TWD2700 = USD83.41 assuming the exchange rate USD.TWD = 32.37, which is current as of Oct 18, 2023.

However TSM was trading between $89-$90 around this time.
Why is there such a big premium (6%) in the US stock market? Did the ADR come to represent more than 5 shares over time?